# Cannot set datetime ticks when using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some series with pandas. However I have a problem when I try to set major locator on axis with dates.

If you want to try on the same dataset as mine, [here's the pickle](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15HUYhWDclxw6VwH_lteNSpAG7-BEGnAt).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')
df = df.set_index('time')

ax = df.plot(y=['dataset1', 'dataset2'], figsize=(10,5))

h_locator = mdates.HourLocator(byhour=[0, 6, 12, 18])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(h_locator)
ax.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I want to display 4 grid ticks per day (hours: 0, 6, 12 and 18) but the output is the same as if I would not set any locator.

[image: plot]

My `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
                     dataset1  dataset2
2018-04-16 00:00:00  0.000000  0.516667
2018-04-16 00:15:00  0.011111  0.244444
2018-04-16 00:30:00  0.000000  0.388889
2018-04-16 00:45:00  0.000000  0.211111
2018-04-16 01:00:00  0.000000  0.127778
                       ...       ...
2018-04-19 22:45:00  0.022222  0.250000
2018-04-19 23:00:00  0.166667  0.505556
2018-04-19 23:15:00  0.000000  0.688889
2018-04-19 23:30:00  0.000000  1.733333
2018-04-19 23:45:00  0.055556  0.283333
[384 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you want to use the `matplotlib.dates` locators and formatters on a plot generated by pandas, you need to plot in compatibility mode,

```
df.plot(..., x_compat=True)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you, I spent about half a day on this and could not find a solution :(